# Problems with removing Symfony2

Tags: arrays, symfony

I have delete action:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $basket = $session->get('basket');
    foreach($basket as $key => $value)
    {
        $ids = $value['id']; 
        //var_dump( $ids, $id); output - string(1) "1" string(1) "1"
        if($ids == $id)
        {
            unset($value[$ids]);
            $session->set('basket', $value);
        }
    }
 return $this->redirectToRoute('index_action');
}
```

and array, which looks like:

```
[
  0 => [
    id => 1
  ], 
  1 => [
    id => 6
  ]
]
```

I want delete item with $id.

I have an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based;

Help me solve this problem, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is not related, i think.

For your original question:

```
unset($basket[$key]);
$session->set('basket', $basket);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: i try like your answer but, i have such array
`[1 => [
    id => 6
  ], 
  2 => [
    id => null
  ]]
` and my item didn't delete

Comment: Thanks, it`s helped. I did that, but apparently forgot to clean up the session )

Answer (score 0):

Your probem there.

```
        unset($value[$ids]);
        $session->set('basket', $value);
```

You before deleted $value. And added to session deleted variabe ($variable).

Comment: I add to the session array without  element which I removed above